# Row-Level Formula

Tags: custom-reports

What is wrong with my formula am getting the following error:

```
IF((AND(ISPICKVAL(STATUS, "RESOLVED")))'&&'((CREATED_DATE - LAST_UPDATE))>48)
```

Warning
Error when encoding row-level formula: Syntax error. Missing ')'

Answer (score 1):

you've used both AND as well as &&,
any one is enough,
you can give a try to either

```
AND((ISPICKVAL(STATUS, "RESOLVED")),((CREATED_DATE - LAST_UPDATE)>48))
```

or

```
(ISPICKVAL(STATUS, "RESOLVED"))&&((CREATED_DATE - LAST_UPDATE)>48)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IF(AND(ISPICKVAL(STATUS, "RESOLVED"), (CREATED_DATE - LAST_UPDATE) > 48), "Action Required", "")
```

can you please check this one?